# Is it possible to transform a Linear Programming problem to a Signomial Problem?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am an electrical engineer who is currently working with some optimization problem. From this "[MM Algorithms for Geometric and Signomial Programming](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.2371)" paper, it seems that although signomial programming is hard and it does not guarantee global solution, local method still exists. Furthermore, it seems that many problem can be expressed as signomial problem.

I was a bit quite fascinated by this prospect, so I am having a quite of a stupid question about the expressive power of signomial programming. Therefore, my question is

Is it possible to reduce/transform/ or present a linear programming problem to a **signomial programming** problem ?

To be honest, my question is just  academic curiosity and it is a little bit stupid because in practice nobody would even make this move.

For example: how to transform this LP problem into a signomial optimization problem

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min }&{{x_1} + {x_2} - {x_3}}\\
{}&{{x_1} + {x_2} \ge 1}\\
{}&{{x_2} - {x_3} \le 4}
\end{array}$

Would you kindly help me with this ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it is possible**.

Each linear constraint can be transformed to a signomial constraint involving a single monomial experssion.

Each equality linear constraint (the same can be done for an inequality constraint) $$a_1x_1 +\dots+a_n x_n =b$$ can be transformed to the following:

$$\alpha \times y_1^{a_1} \dots y_n^{a_n} =1$$

with $\alpha=e^{-b}$ and $y_i>0$ using the transformation:

$$ y_i=e^{x_i}, i=1,\dots,n. $$

Similarly, an objective

$$\min \quad c_1x_1 +\dots+x_n x_n$$

can be given as

$$\min \quad y_1^{c_1}\dots y_n^{c_n}.$$

For the example, first write it as follows:

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min }&{{x_1} + {x_2} - {x_3}}\\
{}&{-{x_1} - {x_2} +1 \le 0}\\
{}&{{x_2} - {x_3} -4\le 0}
\end{array}.$

Then apply $e^x$ anywhere:

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min}&{ e^{{x_1} + {x_2} - {x_3}} }\\
{}&{e^{{-x_1} -{x_2} +1} \le e^0}\\
{}&{e^{{x_2} - {x_3} -4}\le e^0}
\end{array}.$

Now use $y_1,y_2,y_3>0$

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min}&{y_1 y_2 y_3^{-1} }\\
{}&{ e \,y_1^{-1} y_2^{-1}\le 1}\\
{}&{e^{-4} \,y_2 y_3^{-1}\le 1}
\end{array}.$

Comment: thank you ! I have up voted your answer but would you kindly demonstrate your approach on the numerical problem in my edited question ?

Comment: Sure! I just updated the answer.

Comment: Oh in this case it really look like a geometric programming problem !

Comment: As all the coefficients are positive, each function is not only a signomial, but also a posynomial. Hence, it can be considered as geometric programming model.

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Does the system give the bounty of your question as you accepted the solution or do you need to make more action?

Comment: Oh I thought that by accepting your answer it will give you the bounty but I have to do 2 things. First accept the answer, and then manually giving the bounty.

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh thank you!